# VB.NET is it bad practice to use AddHandler to detect when the mouse clicks outside the control?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a bunch of custom controls and one of the features of them is that they highlight when active. For example, the textbox's border will highlight a colour when the user has clicked in it (or it otherwise has input focus) and then default back to a grey colour when the user has clicked outside of the control (INCLUDING ON OTHER CONTROLS)

At the moment I am scanning the parent form and using AddHandler on each of the controls contained within (including children) to find when the user has clicked outside of the control

```
Private Sub GatherChildren(Optional ByVal CTRL As Control = Nothing)
    For Each Child As Object In CTRL.Controls
        If TypeOf Child Is MetroControl Then
            If DirectCast(Child, MetroControl).Controls.Count > 0 Then
                GatherChildren(Child)
            End If
            AddHandler Child.Click, ["LOSE FOCUS FUNCTION"]
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I read somewhere a long time ago that adding handler can seriously reduce the performance and in an environment where I could be having lots of controls on a form. This may seriously impact performance. So my question is, does the AddHandler have a negative effect on performance? If so, is there anymore efficient ways I could solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: How does `.Click` = `["LOSE FOCUS FUNCTION"]`? Logically???

Comment: ["LOSE FOCUS FUNCTION"] is just a substitute for the actual function. I thought putting it that way was more explanatory. It's not important to include the name of the function but MyMouseDown() was what it was actually called

Comment: I know, I just don't think of `lose focus` with a click event.

Comment: If all the buttons/metroControls are laid out on a form wouldn't the form's mousedown event firing prove that there was a click/mouse event that does not belong to any control?

Comment: That would only prove that the user has clicked on the form itself, if the user clicks on another control, the form event does not fire.

Comment: Then your post makes no sense, please update your question.

Comment: What am I missing here?  Why can't you use "Leave" event or "LostFocus" event on the child custom control to reset itself.  And what if use used "TAB" to jump between control.  "Click" event will not cover all scenarios

Comment: Thanks @Nick the *.LostFocus event works for covering clicking the other controls, although I do still have to AddHandler for any parent containers (which is odd), i suppose the event doesnt fire if you click on the container's background because the control still has focus.

Comment: I just tested and if child control inside my user control has logic for "LostFocus" event, it will trigger if i go on some other control.  But you need to Lost Focus handler.   So to your question if its bad, maybe it will degrade your performance a little if you have ALOT of controls, but it will get degraded regardless if you have so many controls on the form

Answer (score 0):

It's only bad practice if you don't unregister the event handlers. On your child controls, provide functionality to register/unregister event handlers. A lot of strange behavior (which is almost always difficult to debug) can occur: like when you register an event handler more than once on the same control. Not to mention memory leaks.

Here's an example I've seen in production code. Oversimplified of course for demonstration.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnAddHandler_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddHandler.Click
        AddHandler btnClickMe.Click, Sub()
                                         txtLog.Text &= "Clicked!" & vbCrLf
                                     End Sub
        txtLog.Text &= "Added event handler." & vbCrLf
    End Sub

End Class
```

For each time you click `btnAddHandler`, `btnClickMe` will append `"Clicked!" & vbCrLf` that many times to txtLog when it is clicked. This is a very simplified example, but if you aren't careful and the events do more significant things, it can make for a fun day of debugging. ;)

No, I wouldn't say it's bad practice to do what you're doing. The sender is distinguishable and as long as you don't do wild things like in the example above, you should be fine.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                With DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
                    AddHandler .GotFocus, AddressOf TextBox_GotFocus
                    AddHandler .LostFocus, AddressOf TextBox_LostFocus
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        DirectCast(sender, TextBox).BackColor = Color.Azure
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        DirectCast(sender, TextBox).BackColor = Color.DimGray
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                With DirectCast(ctrl, TextBox)
                    RemoveHandler .GotFocus, AddressOf TextBox_GotFocus
                    RemoveHandler .LostFocus, AddressOf TextBox_LostFocus
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

This code is perfectly fine.